# Parse MySQLi query statement to get parameters for PDO migration

Tags: php, parsing, mysqli, pdo

This question is about parsing in PHP, not how to migrate MySQLi to PDO.

I want to migrate some old code from MySQLi to PDO. The site has over 400 string query statements. I want to revise the code to use prepared statements.

I.e., convert

```
$query = 'SELECT * from table where x='.$x.' and y > '.$y.' or (z<= 35 and auth like "%ed")'
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

to

```
$query = 'SELECT * from table where x = ? and y > ? or (z <= ? and auth like ?)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param($x, $y, $35, '%ed');
$stmt->execute();
```

I started out by parsing the $query string to find 'where', then looking for 'and' to separate parameter/value pairs, etc.

**Edit**: This is basic code to read lines in a file (in this case, a .php file):

```
$fn = fopen("myfile.php","r+");
while(!feof($fn))  {
    $line = fgets($fn);
    if (strpos($line, 'select'){
       // add parse code here
    };
}
```

when finding a line with a query statement, the line will be a literal string something like this:

> ($line = ) $query = 'select * from menu where authlvl>0 and authlvl<=' .
>   $authlvl . ' order by title';

**Then**, the code to parse may look something like this:

```
$where = substr($line, strpos($line, 'where') + 5);
$pair = array();
$j = 0;
$st = 0;
if (strpos(substr($where, $st), 'and', $st)) > 0){
    while (($and = strpos(substr($where, $st), 'and', $st)) > 0){
        $pair[$j] = trim(substr($where, $st, $and - 1));
        $pair[$j+1] = trim(substr($where, $and + 4));
        $st = $and;
        $j++;
    }
}
$ops = array(' ', '<', '>', '=');
(find operators to identify parameters and values for each pair...)
```

This intuitively is not efficient. Is there a better way to parse the $query string to find the parameters than this? Note that there may be 'order by', etc. in the string that should just append after finding the parameters.

Comment: Of course. I'm writing parsing code to find all query statements and convert them. I have no problem writing the code to revise files. I'm looking for a fundamental way to parse code by looking for key components, such as operators.

Comment: You're being vague. What is exactly present in `$query` in your last piece of code? Is it PHP source code? What does it look like?

Comment: Sounds like a challenging project. But lets looks at this realistically. Being able to write a parser to correctly parse every statement correctly in less time that it will take to edit them manually. 400 may sound like a lot. IT will go faster than one thinks. Look at it this way. If this is a system you need to work on in the long run. You will intimately know the system and train you brain to parse SQL fast.

Comment: I added more details to help understand the specific question.

Comment: susbstr/strpos are wholly inadequate to tackle anything like this. Use some regex detection and extraction, if anything. Also come up with *any* wrapper function instead of smearing parameter binding thin across prepare/bind/execute code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this parsing problem using regex. I am sure that there are much more efficient regex patterns that can be used for matching but this served its purpose.

Reading a line in a PHP file using fgets() yields a string (including the variable name and all syntax), for example:

```
$query = 'select * from menu where authlvl>0 and authlvl<=' . $authlvl . ' order by title';
```

The first step is to confirm that the line of code includes a SELECT statement with a WHERE clause and is not a commented statement. The WHERE clause is taken out and split by and/or to get conditional pairs of parameter/value.

Then the parameter/value pairs can be split to allow rewriting the statement according to PDO.

```
if (preg_match('/(=\s*\'select|=\s*"select)/', $line) && preg_match('/(where)/i', $qry) && !preg_match('/^(\s*\/\/)/', $line)) {
    $z = preg_match('/(?<=where).+/i', $qry, $matches);
    $where = trim($matches[0]);
    $pairs = preg_split('/( and | or )/', $where);
    $andor = preg_match_all('/(\s*and\s*|\s*or\s*)+/', $where, $ao);
```

The conditional pairs are split by finding comparison operators in each pair.

```
preg_match('/.+?(?:[\=<>]+)/', $pair, $par)
preg_match('/[^(' . preg_quote($par[0]) . ')].*/', $pair, $val)
```

The values can then be replaced by question marks and the query statement rewritten. The values can also be placed in an array for PDO.

```
$query = 'select * from menu where authlvl > ? and authlvl <= ? order by title';
$values = array('0', $authlvl);
$stmt = $this->pdosc->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($values);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I was able to use regex to capture nearly any variation of SELECT statements that I have and quickly update (migrate) my files from MySQLi to PDO. Of course, I have a wrapper function that takes either a simple string for the query statement (MySQLi) or a 2 part array with the query and values (PDO).